# Isolation of variables within a trigonometric sum

Tags: functions, trigonometry

is it possible to isolate/separate variables within a trigonometric sum? For example, I can't entirely separate f(a,b) = cos(a+b) into something of the form f(a)f(b) or even f(a)+f(b).
Can you point out any trigonometric identity that can help with that?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said I’m voting to close this question because it is too vague. In the general form you ask, the answer will be "no". If you [edit] the question to tell us just what you want and why we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why you can't.  If there was a way to write
$$\cos(a+b) = f(a)f(b),$$
then it would follow that
$$\cos(2a) = f(a)f(a) = (f(a))^2.$$
But, for certain ranges of $a$, $\cos(2a)<0$ which contradicts the right hand side of the above equation.

Similarly, if $\cos(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$, then $\cos(0) = f(a)+f(-a)$.
Cosine is an even function, which must mean that $f(a) = f(-a)$.  It would follow that
$$\cos(0) = 1 = 2f(a) \implies f(a) = 1/2.$$
Therefore,
$$\cos(2a) = 2f(a) = 2(1/2) = 1.$$
Because the value of $a$ was arbitrary, this would imply that cosine is a constant function, which is false.

I imagine that you might be working with something more complicated, but you might try applying similar logic as for this simple example.

Comment: Yes. Its more complex but your explanation settles it. I was wondering what mathematical manipulation were possible, but its obvious that nothing can be done. Thanks